# How to push or pull to embed array if exists in only a query mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a likes array embed in photos collection. Likes array contains user_id, Every time the user presses the like button, I need to check if the user_id exists in the like array. If it doesn't exist, I push user_id to likes array, else I pull it out of likes array. So I need to perform two queries. I want to encapsulate them in a single query.

Photos:

```
"likes" : [ 
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("")
        }, 
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("")
        }
],
```

Comment: Conditional updates are supported only after MongoDB v4.2. Which version are you using?

Comment: @Mr.S.Sharma I use MongoDB version v4.0.12, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: Two different operations on the same array cannot be performed in v4.0.12.